# Orchard integrating Entity Framework in a module

Tags: c#, entity-framework, orchardcms

Following DB-first approach with EF, I created some entities which I'm trying to access using my `DbContext` - very basic implementation.

But for some reason, I get null tables with the exception:

> 'table.Sql' threw an exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException'

I can't figure out why this is throwing an exception. Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Show us some code...